# how to count the odd numbers from 0 to a given number using recursion?

Tags: c++

the problem asks to crate a recursive function that will count the odd numbers from 0 to a number given this is the code i have:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int count_odd (int count) {
    if (count % 2 == 0) {
        return count / 2;
    }
    else {
        return count_odd((count/2)+1); // i know this part is wrong
    }

    return count;
}

int main() {
    int num;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> num;

    if (num < 0) {
        std::cout << "Invalid input.\n";
    } else {
        int odd;

        odd = count_odd(num);

        std::cout << "The number of odds from 0 to " << num << " is " << odd << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the first part of the 'if' statement in the count_odd function returns the number of odds when an even integer is inputted, however how would i count the odds when an odd int is inputted? i know a recursive function has to call itself

Comment: The problem wants you explicitly *count* them, not determine how many they are through a formula. As in “if this is odd, add one, otherwise don’t”. Your base case should be “count is zero”, not “count is even”.

Comment: @cppnoob you should consider accepting one of the answers and "closing" this question, if your issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 1):

While the answers you have been given so far does produce the correct answer for your specific case, I would argue that they do not really show recursion. Instead they use the specifics of your problem to take shortcuts, which - given that your problem sounds very homework'y - is missing the point a bit.

The basic point of recursion is that you have a problem for which the base case is easy to solve, AND for which it is easy to give a solution for `n+1` (or `n-1`) given that you have a solution for `n`.

In this case I would select `0` as the base case, and say that it is not an odd number (or an even one for that matter; 0 is special). This gives us this code:

```
    if (number == 0)
        return 0;
```

Secondly, if we know that there are `X` odd numbers in all the previous numbers. Then, if the current number is odd the current count is `X+1`, and if it is even the current count is `X`. That gives us this:

```
    if (number % 2 == 0)
        // even
        return countOdd(number - 1);
    else
        // odd
        return countOdd(number - 1) + 1;
```

Then if we put it together, the result is this:

```
#include <iostream>

int countOdd(int number)
{
    if (number == 0)
        return 0;

    if (number % 2 == 0)
        // even
        return countOdd(number - 1);
    else
        // odd
        return countOdd(number - 1) + 1;
}

int main()
{
    int number = 9;
    std::cout << "There are " << countOdd(number) << " odd numbers from 0 to " << number << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ps. I chose 0 for the base case because I think that that is the overwhelmingly most logical choice. If it is a strong requirement that you must go from 0 to n, then this should give you enough to go on to reverse the logic yourself (hint: You need to add the "count to" number to the arguments and carry it along unchanged to the end).

Answer (score 0):

Call the `count_odd` function with `count` either augmented or decremented to the next even number, depending on whether the input number should be counted or not:

```cpp
int count_odd (int count) {
    if (count % 2 == 0) {
        return count / 2;
    }

    return count_odd(count + 1); // or -1 if the upper bound should not be counted
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! i had put this `````c++ return count - count_odd(count - 1); this is the same right?

Comment: @navarr232 it's not the same, but it does work. I edited the answer to explain why.

Answer (score 0):

including a main plus a bit of error checking here...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void count(int currentTotal, int destinationNumber) {
        cout << "current count is " << (currentTotal / 2) << " heading for" << destinationNumber << "\n";
        if(currentTotal < destinationNumber)
        {
                count(currentTotal+=2, destinationNumber);
        }
}

int main (void){
        int destinationNumber = 0;
        cout << "Enter a number here: ";
        cin >> destinationNumber;
        cout << "You entered the number " << destinationNumber << ".\n";
        // a little bit of error checking here... we only want odd numbers, right?
        if (destinationNumber % 2 == 0)
        {
                cout << destinationNumber << " is an even number.\n";
        } else {
                count(0, destinationNumber);
        }
        return 0;
}
```